# Why Does heapq Use the Front of the List?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with python's heapq implementation. I understand what it does, but I don't understand why it uses the front of the list, rather than the back to store the smallest element? I would have expected this to be slow, given the cost of shifting around elements at the start of a list.

Can anyone provide clarity on why heapq uses the front of the list, and why this is does not cause it to be slow?

```
>>> import heapq
>>> A = [10,3,5,2,1,3,5]
>>> heapq.heapify(A)
>>> A
[1, 2, 3, 10, 3, 5, 5]
>>> heapq.heappop(A)
1
>>> A
[2, 3, 3, 10, 5, 5]
```

Comment: Hello G Harding, and welcome to SO! In your question, you want to be clear and organized. When you say "and why this is does not cause it to be slow?" Is there any reason it would be slow? You have to include all the info in your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`heappop` is using last element. It calls `_siftup` with the element popped at position -1  (see: `heap.pop()`). If you look closely, it returns the first element as noted in `returnitem` as return value, but it in no way pops this item or use this value in the algorithm.

heapq.py:

```
def heappop(heap):
    """Pop the smallest item off the heap, maintaining the heap invariant."""
    lastelt = heap.pop()    # raises appropriate IndexError if heap is empty
    if heap:
        returnitem = heap[0]
        heap[0] = lastelt
        _siftup(heap, 0)
        return returnitem
    return lastelt
```

## References

CPython heapq: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Lib/heapq.py#L135-L143

Answer (score 1):

`heappop` does not pop from the front of the list. It pops from the back of the list then replaces the first item with the last item and sifts up. There's no mass shifting of the heap except for the sifting, which is required anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The point of heapq is to use a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) structure – a binary heap, specifically, where each node is less than or equal to all of its descendants. The [pop operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Extract) always moves around O(log n) elements, so it doesn’t matter in that sense which order the list is in (it’s not like `.pop(0)`, which would move O(n) elements – notice how the list is `[2, 3, 3, 10, 5, 5]` after the operation, not `[2, 3, 10, 3, 5, 5]`). The remaining consideration is just making the tree structure easy to produce from the list, and that’s accomplished in the most straightforward way by having the root at the start, where the children of each node at index *i* are at indexes 2i + 1 and 2i + 2.